# iterative function - divide and conquer function

Tags: algorithm

I'm just in the beginning of studying algorithm analysis and design course?
and I just want to know:
What's the difference between iterative function and divide and conquer function?
Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide and conquer From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) :

> A divide and conquer algorithm works by recursively breaking down a problem into two or more sub-problems of the same (or related) type, until these become simple enough to be solved directly.

Iterative function from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) :

> In this process, starting from some initial number, the result of applying a given function is fed again in the function as input, and this process is repeated.

So they are not same

Comment: Thank you...
but how to translate something like :
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + N into a code, let's say C++ code?
is there any method to solve question like this?

Answer (score 0):

A divide and conquer algorithm will split the problem into smaller pieces and you solve the smaller pieces and then aggregate to get to the final solution.

An iterative algorithm is where you try to solve the entire problem by going over the entire problem.

This is by no means an authorative reply.

Thanks to blackbear for the suggestion.

Iterative example of Fibonacci series  would be something like this

http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Scala)

And a divide and conquer method would be like this

```
def fibo(n:Int):Int = { if(n==1 || n==0) 1 else fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)}
```

Hope these examples add more clarity

Comment: I'd add a couple of examples like the merge sort and the selection sort, typical teached algorithms the OP should know